How can I get rid of this console error from apexcharts
Error:

<g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN, 0) scale(1)".

Here is the code
$(document).ready(function () {
    var codeChartData = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(codeList));
    console.log(codeChartData);

    var seriesData = codeChartData.map(item => parseInt(item.count));

    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            height: 600,
            events: {
                legendClick: function (chartContext, seriesIndex, config) {
                    handleLegendClick(chartContext, seriesIndex, config, codeChartData);
                }
            }
        },
        series: seriesData,
        labels: codeChartData.map(item => item.statusName),
        theme: {
            mode: 'light',
            palette: 'palette1'
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            onItemClick: {
                toggleDataSeries: false
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                expandOnClick: false
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 480,
            options: {
                chart: {
                    width: 200
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#errorCountChartdiv"), options);
    chart.render();
});

function handleLegendClick(chartContext, seriesIndex, config, codeChartData) {
    var statusCode = codeChartData[seriesIndex].statusCode;
    console.log("Clicked seriesIndex:", seriesIndex);
    console.log("StatusCode:", statusCode);

    $('#errorDetailModal').modal('show');
    $("#errorDetailModalTitle").html(chartContext.w.config.labels[seriesIndex]);
    $("#errorDetailModalBody").html("<i>Loading...</i>");

    
    $.post("/Dashboard/ErrorDetails", {
        code: statusCode,
        fromTime: "@ViewBag.ErrorFromTime",
        toTime: "@ViewBag.ErrorToTime",
        endPoint: "@ViewBag.endPoint",
        i_customer: "@ViewBag.i_customer",
        i_account: "@ViewBag.i_account",
        ingress_adjacency: "@ViewBag.ingress_adjacency"
    }, function (data) {
        $("#errorDetailModalBody").html(data);
    });

    return false;
}

The chart is working fine it's just that I'm getting this error on console.
In this code I have added a pie chart from apexcharts
and I'm populating it with status code , count & status Name that I'm getting from api
and on clicking Label
I open a modal in which I'm getting data matching with index & statuscode from another api
The chart is working exactly as it is expected but I'm getting this error in console that I'm not able to resolve
Please help me fix this.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The Console error should indicate which JavaScript file the code is in and what Line the code was on, in that file. I am not seeing a reference in the code you posted, so I suspect it is another library file that is throwing it. It may help to provide a [mcve].

It may be related to this line, var seriesData = codeChartData.map(item => parseInt(item.count)); I wonder if item.count is null. When this is passed to parseInt() it would result in NaN or Not a Number.
